# How to download and display images from firebase storage

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-storage

Can anyone help me set up this code to retrieve my images that is saved in firebase storage. I tried using this code to display my image from firebase storage but it's not working for me the image is not appearing I received this error in the debugger

> bucket= bucket=gs://cross-saint-inoper-609a6.appspot.com, data={length = 65, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 2e220a20 207d0a7d }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, NSLocalizedDescription=Object jumpimages does not exist., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, ResponseErrorCode=404}), data={length = 65, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 2e220a20 207d0a7d }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, NSLocalizedDescription=Object jumpimages does not exist., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, ResponseErrorCode=404})

The images are saved in a folder as 'jumpimages' in firebase storage but I receive the error saying they don't exist How do I fix this code to get my image

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
let imageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://cross-saint-inoper-609a6.appspot.com/jumpimages/")
  
imageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 2024 * 2024) { data, error in
    func addImage(imageName img: String) {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.frame = self.view.frame
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        if let profileImage = UIImage(named: img) {
            image.image = profileImage
        }
        self.view.addSubview(image)
    }        
    if error != nil {
        print("image downloaded successfully")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is explaining exactly what is going on.

The image you are trying to download is **1060192** bytes long, but in your code, you set a maximum of **1048576**, which is **11616** bytes less than the image size.

Try increasing your maxSize, that should be enough to at least change the error.

Comment: I did increase the and now I get no image and no error @GabrielNexT

Comment: Unfortunately I have never programmed for ios, only android, but shouldn't you use data for something?
Here is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#download_in_memory) where they pass data as a parameter to UIImage

Comment: @Parlor From the error message, it seems that the file path you entered is wrong, as it is saying that the file does not exist. Check through the firebase interface if you are passing the correct path. Go to Storage, click on the file and then copy the file location that will appear in a window on the right. [Image](https://imgur.com/a/To99r2y)